# Doubts about db_index, primary_key and unique parameters

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to improve my code. I've some doubts about db_index, primary_key and unique parameters.

```
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    #=================================================================================#

    class Country(models.Model):
        country_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, verbose_name="Id", editable=False)
        name = models.CharField(unique=True, db_index=True, max_length=50, verbose_name="Nome")
        short_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=5, verbose_name="Abreviatura")

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "País"
            verbose_name_plural = "Países"
            ordering = ['name']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

    #=================================================================================#   

    class State(models.Model):
        state_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, verbose_name="Id", editable=False)
        state = models.CharField(unique=True, db_index=True, max_length=2, verbose_name="Sigla")
        name = models.CharField(unique=True, db_index=True, max_length=20, verbose_name="Nome")
        region = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Região")
        country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name="País")

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Estado"
            verbose_name_plural = "Estados"
            ordering = ['name']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

    #=================================================================================#

    class City(models.Model):
        city_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False) # id baseado no IBGE
        name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=150, verbose_name="Nome") # db_index para otimizar desempenho
        short_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Slug")    
        state = models.ForeignKey(State, verbose_name="Estado")

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Cidade"
            verbose_name_plural = "Cidades"
            ordering = ['name']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return ('%s - %s') % (self.name, self.state.state)

    #=================================================================================#

    class Phone(models.Model): 
        PHONES_TYPE_CHOICES = (
            ('R', u'Residencial'),
            ('M', u'Celular'),
            ('C', u'Comercial'),
        )

        user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Usuário')
        type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PHONES_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Tipo')
        number = models.CharField('Número', max_length=15)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Telefone"
            verbose_name_plural = "Telefones"

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.number

    #=================================================================================#

    class Address(models.Model):
        STREETS_TYPE_CHOICES = (
            ('R', 'Rua'),
            ('A', 'Avenida'),
            ('T', 'Travessa'),
            ('E', 'Estrada'),
            ('R', 'Rodovia'),
            ('Q', 'Quadra'),
            ('B', 'Bloco'),
        )

        user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Usuário')
        street_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STREETS_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Logradouro')
        street = models.CharField('Endereço', max_length=100)
        number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Número')
        complement = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, verbose_name='Complemento')
        neighborhood = models.CharField('Bairro', max_length=100)
        state = models.ForeignKey(State, verbose_name="Estado")
        city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name="Cidade")
        country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name="País")
        zip_code = models.CharField('CEP', max_length=10)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Endereço"
            verbose_name_plural = "Endereços"

        def __unicode__(self):
            return ("%s, %s") % (self.city, self.state)

    #=================================================================================#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it introspected DB or newly created models? If it is created, you do not need `SOMETHING_id` fields, Django creates primary keys automatically.

Always use unicode strings (`u'something'`) for everything that is displayed to user and can contain non-ascii characters.

You don't need parenthesis around string in `__unicode__`

And the best way to set indexes is to analyze real queries that are being ran on specific model. Every new index slows down `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries so do not use indexes if you don't need them. Also, in most cases indexes for chars work good only in `exact` or `startswith` comparisons (in Django terms). If you are using `contains` - index is useless.

Comment: Thank you! It's a introspected DB (this is the reason to use the custom ID). Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

If `primary_key=True` set to field then `unique=True` is redundant.
`unique=True` also assumes that `db_index=True`